# Android Emulator for working with Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I couldn't find Smartface Android emulator in Google Play. Could anyone know where can I download Smartface Android emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the Smartface Android Emulator app's link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.smartface.developerApp